# Folding of wave-vector in Band Theory of Metals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

In the [Kronig-Penney model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig.E2.80.93Penney_model) in the Band Theory of Metals, we derive the energy levels as function of wave vector as shown in the figure.
[image: energy vs wave-vector]

But my professor showed that we represent the levels folded from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. This is also represented on the [Wolfram Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheKronigPenneyModel/) on the model.

Why do we do it? What's the point I am missing?

Comment: The point you are missing is Bloch's theorem - since the potential is periodic, you can fold everything back into the first Brillouin zone.

Comment: @JonCuster But it doesn't physically mean anything, does it? My prof's words made it look like it does. So, it's just a way of representing the picture?

Comment: Garyp's answer below is most of it.  While the two representations are equivalent, the reduced scheme will be used for almost everything.  In addition, the extended scheme does not make clear which transitions so not require any momentum changes - only the reduced form does. Get used to using and seeing the reduced form.  The extended form, a teaching tool, has pretty much done its job at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My answer to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/104413/5739) might help.

The short version is that due to the periodic nature of the potential, a wave vector $k$ is *identically the same* as the wave vector $k+2\pi/a$.  There are at least two ways of showing bands on a graph.  One is the *extended zone scheme* which you have shown above.  The other is the *reduced zone scheme* where we take advantage of the periodicity of $k$, and show all the vectors in the interval $(-\pi/a, \pi/a)$.  The bands appear folded back in this scheme.  More details in the cited answer.